# Hibernate, parameterLists and lists of objects

Tags: hibernate

I have a list of Products (Products is id, name, price etc.).
The products are referred to by id (not linked in the hibernate xml) in another table reporting.

I want to have a method that will receive a list of products and then take those products and generate a where x in (productlist).  My hql looks like this:

```
SELECT category, SUM(id.downloadTrackingCount) " +
"FROM Reporting " +
"WHERE (id.productId IN (:products)) AND (id.fullDownloadDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate) " +
"GROUP BY category";
```

But when I try to setParameter on the productlist I get an error saying cannot cast Products to Integer.  Is there some method that I can use that will tell Hibernate to do a getId on each product in the list and then fill that in for the :products parameter?

Answer (score 2):

I think that your best bet is to walk over product list and collect id values into separate list to use as a parameter. Note that you will need to consider corner cases such as empty list and list with more entries that `IN` clause can handle.

Comment: That is what I thought, I was just hoping beyond hope.

Comment: It's probably not that bad :) `IN` can take only that many items so you will have pretty small number of iterations.